# New hard drive fails to format but has no errors in surface scan

Tags: hard-drive, hardware-failure

I added added a new 6tb WD Blue into my build just a few days ago, and started formatting it before going to bed in Windows Disk Management. It was on about 5% when I left it, and after about 10 hours it was stuck at 22%. The computer hadn't even slept, so not sure what cause the interruption but perhaps it being a bad drive.

**What I've done so far:**

I then cancelled the format and attempted to delete the volume to try and format the drive from scratch except I'd get an I/O Error, so I change the sata cable and the port on the motherboard to rule out any hardware being the issue other than the HDD itself, but I still got the I/O error.

I then successfully changed the drive letter as I read that can help, but the error persisted.

I couldn't use chkdsk because the drive needs to be formatted for it to work and it's not (it's listed as RAW).

I then tried to format again with Disk Manager, it "..was not successful".

Then I tried to use Mini Partition Wizard to delete the partitions, and I thought it said it managed to do it successfully, but the drive was then listed as a bad drive in the program, I tried to restart but it windows was hanging because of the drive (previously windows was acting funny and then wouldn't as soon as I disconnected the drive). I had to force a shutdown (this wasn't the only time I had to do that). *[Image: Partition Wizard "Bad Disk"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUqRo.png)*.

When I booted back up the drive was listed in Partition Wizard with the partition as it was and not as bad. So it must not have managed to do anything?

Now I've used WD's Diagnostics Program, as soon as it was opened it had a fail for the SMART status. I then ran the short test, the drive passed it.

An Aside: Clean installed windows on a brand new main drive, not the 6tb

I ran the surface test in Partition Wizard and it came back with no errors. *[Image: Partition Wizard Succesful Surface Scan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwXMf.png)*.That threw me, thought there was going to be bad sectors. So not sure if the drive is actually broken or not.

Any thoughts are appreciated. Likely will send it back tomorrow if I can't find a solution.

Comment: If it's new, send it back.

Comment: Yeah sounds like a bad drive. WD support might have a few more things you could try but I doubt it.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I've put in for a replacement, so Amazon is sending out a new one straight away. So all good, thanks for the help, should have replaced as soon as it failed once, just thought their might have been some simple solution.

Comment: @wjandrea I just decided to put in for a replacement, I've spent a fair amount of time over the last few days trying to troubleshoot it, figured I'd be better to send it off now rather than dive in even deeper. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was brand new, the answer was to just to replace it. The replacement is up and running and did a full format (in about 10 hours) just fine, on the same cable and port that the original one failed to format on. So as the commenters said, it was likely just a bad drive that needed to be replaced.